# Convert double groupby object into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am using my dataframe with a datetime field to generate a monthly return series over different tickers.

```
return_series=data.groupby([data['Date'].dt.year,data['Date'].dt.month]).apply(monthly_returns)
```

The current output looks something like this, where the tuple values are pnl,capital and return.

```
Date  Date
2008  6         (-742.58, 150001.16, -0.495049504951)
      7         (123142.08, 299304.14, 41.1427920777)
      8         (-5963.05, 426217.67, -1.39906212711)
      9       (-137316.34, 868529.72, -15.8102062414)
      10             (4503.44, 685906.3, 0.656567814)
```

I would like to separate out the tuple to three columns (Capital,PnL,Returns) and  change the Dates columns to show Year,Month.

The monthly return function aggregates over symbols for a given month

def monthly_returns(df_monthly):

symbols_pnl=df_monthly.groupby(df_monthly['Symbol']).apply(symbol_return)
      symbols_invested_capital=df_monthly.groupby(df_monthly['Symbol']).apply(symbol_capital)

return(sum(symbols_pnl),sum(symbols_invested_capital),sum(symbols_pnl)/sum(symbols_invested_capital)*100)

The input data daily position values

Date    Symbol  Position    Prev Position   Price   Exec Price
6/24/2008   ABC 100 0   5   4.85
6/25/2008   EFG 200 150 10  9.8

Comment: Can you show us what your `monthly_returns` function looks like? Also, some example input data would help.

Comment: In your question, please, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the tuple into multiple columns can be done using something like this

```
data[['Capital', 'PnL', 'Returns']] = data[column_name_tuple].apply(pd.Series)
```